# Wordpress - How to read Post HTML output after 1 shortcode execution

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have custom WP plugin, which registers some shortcodes and run them in Post typically.
One Post typically has 2 or more of these shortcodes.
I need to find out if the first shortcode was executed and changed Post HTML somehow - so the second and next runs of shortcode don´t replace the HTML made by first shortcode run.

But I don´t know how.

I know, that it should be done by adding some parameter to shortcode like [shortcode first_run="true"], but it is the last acceptable solution, because it demands changing of previously generated shortcodes in Posts.
I know I can´t use get_the_content() - it shows the Post content from DB before shortcode runs.
I know I can´t use the_content() - cause it cycle the WP run

Thank you for help.

My sample of code (it doesn´t help too much I guess, but.. just to imagination):

```
function joreviewstable_func( $atts ) {
    
    
    if (is_singular() || is_tag() ) {
            $a = shortcode_atts( array(
            'type' => "",
            'id' => NULL,
            'params' => NULL,
            'limit' => NULL,
            'tablesorter_disable' => NULL,
            'disallow_images' => NULL,
            'product_ids' => NULL,
            'manufacturer' => NULL,
            'manufacturer_serie' => NULL,
            'no_sum' => NULL,
            'custom_order' => NULL,
            'vertical_design' => NULL
        ), $atts );
    
    
        require_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'inc/shortcode.php');
    
        $return = jo_reviews_shortcode_generate_table( $a['type'], $a['id'], $a['params'],
                                                        $a['limit'], $a['tablesorter_disable'], $a['disallow_images'],
                                                        $a['product_ids'], $a['manufacturer'], $a['manufacturer_serie'],
                                                        $a['no_sum'], $a['custom_order'], $a['vertical_design'] );
        //$return = "<table><tr><td>data</td></tr></table>";
    
        return $return;
    } else {
      return NULL;
    }
add_shortcode( 'joreviewstable', 'joreviewstable_func' );
```

The jo_reviews_shortcode_generate_table function do some magic and returns html back to joreviewstable_func.

But I don´t know, how to get the edited Post HTML to strpos if it contains something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using global variables.

f.e.

```
function joreviewstable_func( $atts ) {
  global $first_run;
  if(!empty($first_run)) return;
  $first_run=1;
  //REST LINES HERE
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Thanks for this. Global vars are perfect solution.